# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1 Incorrect syntax near '>'

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server Procedure like this:

```
//Beginning of procedure 
   SELECT 
          CASE IDNumber
                 WHEN (DATALENGTH(IDNumber)>7) 
                  THEN SUBSTRING(IDNumber,0,6)
                 WHEN (DATALENGTH(IDNumber) < 7)
                  THEN CONCAT((REPLICATE(0,7-LEN(IDNumber)),IDNumber)
          END AS NID

//Rest of the procedure here
```

the code on execution throws the error `Incorrect syntax near '>'.` on line `WHEN (DATALENGTH(IDNumber)>7)` .

`IDNumber` is a `nvarchar`. I tried using `LEN(IDNumber)` but in vain.
I don't know what the error is!

Comment: remove the IDNumber immediatly after the CASE. Also you parentheses aren't needed around (DATALENGTH....) but they aren't hurting anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite your query like that:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN DATALENGTH(IDNumber) > 7 THEN SUBSTRING(IDNumber, 0, 6)
        WHEN DATALENGTH(IDNumber) < 7 THEN CONCAT(REPLICATE(0, LEN(IDNumber)), IDNumber)
    END AS NID;
```

When you write `CASE Column`, you have to compare it to direct values, not to an expression.

Comment: REPLICATE Function Requires 2 arguments. CONCAT(REPLICATE(0, 7, LEN(IDNumber)), IDNumber)  need to be change

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, when should I provide an expression or a column name to Select [column or expression] ? Or, is it not the appropriate way?

Comment: @b.g you should use _Select CASE [column or expression]_ only when comparing equality, such as `SELECT CASE Name WHEN 'Evaldas' THEN <EXP> WHEN 'Muhammad' THEN <EXP2> END`, which would be the same as doing `SELECT CASE WHEN Name = 'Evaldas' (...)`

Comment: @b.g What Gabriel said :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have case variable then you need to provide values to When part, not the condition